# Power BI embed with authentication C# on WinForms

Tags: winforms, powerbi

I want to embed a powerBi report on a winform that I have. The question is about the autentication. I cant get an automatic "log on" directly from my app. And when I put the link generated on PBI it doesn´t have the ID but doesnt show me the log in page either.

Any sugestion will be apreciated.

Comment: You'll need to use a WebView control and read about Power BI Embedding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-analytics-power-bi